# How to combine two input fields and open as URL for different URL combination?

Tags: php, url, merge, user-input

My website customer frequently looking tracking details, every time they need to go different types courier website and enter tracking id.

All my courier websites tracking url position same, 1) courier website 2) id

eg:  (More than one courier service and their respective tracking URL)

> 1) www.courier.com?trackingid=**12345**
>
> 2) www.courier.in/track/id=**1234**&type=0&service=0

How to merge two input fields.

eg:

[image]

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        Select Courier :
        <select name="courier">
            <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option value="professional_courier">Professional Courier</option>
            <option value="india_post">India Post</option>
        </select>

        Trackingid: <input type="text" name="trackingid"><br>
        <input type="submit">

    </form>
    <?php
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    // if (!empty($_POST)): header("Location: https://www.tpcindia.com/Tracking2014.aspx?id=".$_POST["trackingid"]."&type=0&service=0");
    // endif;


    if (!empty($_POST['courier']) && !empty($_POST['trackingid'])) {
        switch ($_POST['courier']) {
            case 'professional_courier':
                $url = "https://www.tpcindia.com/Tracking2014.aspx?id=".$_POST["trackingid"]."&type=0&service=0";
                break;
            case 'india_post':
                $url = "https://www.indiapost.gov.in/_layouts/15/dop.portal.tracking/trackconsignment.aspx";
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Unknown courier "%s"', $_POST['courier']));

                header('Location: ' . $url);
        };
    };
    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Not working. for single url its working(see below working code),

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<body>

<form action="#" method="post">
Select Courier :
<select name="courier">
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="professional_courier">Professional Courier</option>
  <option value="india_post">India Post</option>
</select>

Trackingid: <input type="text" name="trackingid"><br>
<input type="submit">

</form>



<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)): header("Location: https://www.tpcindia.com/Tracking2014.aspx?id=".$_POST["trackingid"]."&type=0&service=0");
endif;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your html part also.

Comment: @jagad89 My Code https://justpaste.it/3vhjo how can i add more than one url combination,  i have 2 separate url for 2 courier service my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally working, thanks to everyone.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

    <form action="#" method="POST">
        Select Courier :
        <select name="courier">
            <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option value="professional_courier">Professional Courier</option>
            <option value="india_post">India Post</option>
        </select>

        Trackingid: <input type="text" name="trackingid">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['courier'])) {
        if ('professional_courier' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.tpcindia.com/Tracking2014.aspx?id=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&type=0&service=0");
        } else if ('india_post' === $_POST['courier']) {
            header("Location: https://www.dhl.com/en/express/tracking.html?AWB=" . $_POST["trackingid"] . "&brand=DHL");
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  var x = $('#select1').val();
  var y =  $('#select2').val();
  window.location.href = 'https://www.' + x + '.com?trackingid=' + y;
});
```

Comment: How to add more than one -  window.location.href, fedex courier tracking url different from others. @aleksaRazer22

Comment: @zus you can add values to select 1 options like: select1 val -> www.abc.com?trackingid= , select2 val -> www.xyz.in?track=

Comment: If more than one url combination, how can write the code. My code => paste.ofcode.org/NfbcFUFvh5pv6cvpGNeHJ6 @aleksaRazer22

Comment: updated code => paste.ofcode.org/yz6SfE28L7sy9zkKy2Wn7h

Answer (score 1):

Hey it is very simple can check this example with PHP code user header location and pass your tracking after post

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<body>

<form action="#" method="post">

<select name="cm_id">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

Trackingid: <input type="text" name="trackingid"><br>
<input type="submit">

</form>

<?php if (!empty($_POST)): header("Location: http://localhost/test.php?trackingid=".$_POST["trackingid"]); endif;?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to add more than one window.open(), like abc -> www.abc.com?trackingid=123 & xyx -> www.xyz.in?track=12345

Comment: We are so sorry but we don't understand can you please explain a bit more so we will give you the best solution

Comment: 1) abc courier service url like -> /localhost/test.php?trackingid=".$_POST["trackingid"])    2) xyz courier service url like -> localhost/test.php/track?id=".$_POST["trackingid"]) here both the url different right? How can i add more than one url combination in if condition?

Comment: any help more than one url => paste.ofcode.org/xCgWhqRjNqE7tgNrQi9Wyn

Comment: Can i get Any help @ Pixlogix

Comment: Hey @zus we will update you soon with example give us time thank you

Comment: @zus, For that you will have to add the multi select for dropdown so you can select multiple option and then in PHP side you will have to get this and make the for loop and then in the for loop you can add window.open() code so you will add multiple

Comment: My code : paste.ofcode.org/NfbcFUFvh5pv6cvpGNeHJ6 any help thanks @Pixlogix

Comment: updated code => paste.ofcode.org/yz6SfE28L7sy9zkKy2Wn7h

Answer (score 0):

I assume you using jQuery and this is your html form

```
<form action="#">
  <select name="courier" id="courier">
    <option value="www.abc.com">ABC</option>
    <option value="www.xyz.com">XYZ</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="tracknumber" id="tracknumber">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

To handle what you expect, use on click event jquery

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var courier = $('#courier').val();
  var tracknumber = $('#tracknumber').val();
  window.open(courier+'?trackingid='+tracknumber, '_blank');
});
```

This is the complete code with multiple courier.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Courier Tracking</title>
    <script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <select name="courier" id="courier" multiple>
            <option value="http://example.com">ABC</option>
            <option value="http://example2.com">XYZ</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="tracknumber" id="tracknumber">
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#submit').click(function()
        {
            var courier = $('#courier').val();
            var tracknumber = $('#tracknumber').val();
            $.each(courier, function( index, value ) {
                  window.open(value+'?id='+tracknumber, '_blank');
                });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: How to add more than one window.open(), like abc -> www.abc.com?trackingid=123 &  xyx -> www.xyz.in?track=12345 @Amal Triadi

Comment: use multiple select, then loop the selected value when button clicked

Comment: Hey amal then you have to use jquery with a trigger event and also use set time out

Comment: ya, use set time out if needed @Pixlogix

Comment: include jquery before you use script in your html @Gem

Comment: I changed the post, with the complete code link @zus

Comment: @Spy.Murad If i add more than one url combination how can i use within if condition => window.open(courier+'?trackingid='+tracknumber, '_blank');

Comment: @Spy.Murad I have 2 different URL combination,  1) window.open(value+'?id='+tracknumber, '_blank');     2) window.open(value+'?tracking_id_is='+tracknumber, '_blank');

Comment: abc courier using window.open(value+'?id='+tracknumber, '_blank'); & xyz courier using window.open(value+'?tracking_id_is='+tracknumber, '_blank');

Comment: then just modify the value abc option to `value="http://example.com?id="` and xyz to `value="http://example.com?tracking_id_is="` and modify the js `window.open(value+tracknumber, '_blank')` @zus

Comment: @Spy.Murad One my courier tracking url look like, www.courier.com?id=123&type=0&service=0, FYI after id the url contains &type=0&service=0 how can include this?

Comment: @zus the order of query string has no effect based on their position. there is no problem if `id` placed at the last

Comment: my code => paste.ofcode.org/NfbcFUFvh5pv6cvpGNeHJ6 could you pls help me?

Comment: Updated code => paste.ofcode.org/yz6SfE28L7sy9zkKy2Wn7h